# open graph news.reads doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, article

I've some trouble with my sharing dialog. When i use books.reads type action everything works, ShareDialog works,and post news to facebook, but when i use news.reads or news.publishes type share dialog appears only when i try to share from developer's facebook account.

books.reads action works good:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("og:type", "books.book")
                    .putString("og:url", "http://www.google.com")
                    .putString("og:title", "title")
                    .putString("og:description", "text")
                    .putString("og:image","imageURL")
                    .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
                    .build();
            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType("books.reads")
                    .putObject("book", object)
                    .build();
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                    .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
                    .setAction(action)
                    .build();
            ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
            shareDialog.show(content);
```

news.reads works only for developer's facebook account, and SareDialog doesn't appear for other accounts:

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "article")
            .putString("og:url", "http://www.google.com")
            .putString("og:title", "title")
            .putString("og:description", "text")
            .putString("og:image","imageURL")
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("news.reads")
            .putObject("article", object)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("article")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.show(content);
```

facebook return error message:"{FacebookServiceException: httpResponseCode: -1, facebookErrorCode: 100, facebookErrorType: null, message: App 2012491665000000 is not allowed to create actions of type news:Read for user 115892459000000}"

Should I get any permissions or I missed something?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ? I'm having the same problem using iOS SDK ... Works fine with books but not articles ... Thanks